# How to access attribute from XML

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to access my marking attribute from my XML file. However, what I do know is that I'm doing it wrongly, but I don't know why, and how to fix it

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.emf.validation">
  <constraintProvider
        cache="true"
        mode="Live">
     <package
           namespaceUri="http://mbse/project/yawlnets">
     </package>    

     <constraints categories="org.pnml.tools.epnk.validation">
        <constraint
              id="model.project.validation.arc"
              lang="OCL"
              mode="Live"
              name="Arc"
              severity="ERROR"
              statusCode="400">
           <message>

           </message>
           <description>

           </description>
           <target
                 class="Arc:http://mbse/project/yawlnets">
              <event
                    name="Set">
                 <feature
                       name="source">
                 </feature>
                 <feature
                       name="target">
                 </feature>
                 <feature
                       name="type">
                 </feature>
              </event>
           </target>            
           <![CDATA[
             ( self.source.oclIsKindOf(YAWLPlaces::PlaceTypes.END) and //HERE
               self.target.oclIsKindOf(YAWLPlaces::PlaceTypes.START) and //HERE
               self.type->size() = 0 )
           ]]>
        </constraint>      
     </constraints>
  </constraintProvider>
```

I've commented where the problems are. YAWLPlaces is my java class that has the PlaceTypes start and end

EDIT:

```
private int getMarking(Place place) {
    if (this.place instanceof Place) {
        PlaceMarking marking = place.getMarking();
        if (marking != null) {
            switch (marking.getText().getValue()) {
            case PlaceTypes.START_VALUE:
                return 0;   
            case PlaceTypes.END_VALUE:
                return 1;
            }
        } 
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: How are you parsing this?  Depending on the XML parser CDATA may be skipped.

Comment: Have edited the post

Comment: How does your code related to parsing XML?